# Python pandas: delete the data in a data frame that the size of data is below a value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.5

I have a data frame called df(this is just example, the real data is big, please consider the computing speed) as following:

```
   name   id     text
    tom    1      a1 
    lucy   2      b1
    john   3      c1
    tick   4      d1
    tom    1      a2 
    lucy   2      b2
    john   3      c2
    tick   4      d2
    tom    1      a3 
    lucy   2      b3
    john   3      c3
    tick   4      d3
    tom    1      a4 
    tick   4      d4
    tom    1      a5 
    lucy   2      b5
    tick   4      d5
```

the dataframe can be grouped by the name(tom, john, lucy, tick). I want to delete the data that the size of each group(by name)is less 5. I mean since the size of name of lucy and john is less 5, I want to delete these data and get the new df(just have tick and tom data), such as.

Could you tell me how to do it,please! Thanks!

Comment: thanks for your comments, I have updated my question.  it is less 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use a filter for this. It would only be one line:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['tom','lucy','john','tick','tom','lucy','john','tick', 'tom', 'lucy','john','tick','tom','tick','tom', 'lucy','tick'], 'id':[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,4,1,2,4],'text':['a1','b1','c1','d1','a2','b2','c2','d2','a3','b3','c3','d3','a4','d4','a5','b5','d5']})

df.groupby('name').filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 5)
```

and the output is only Tick and Tom:

```
   id  name text
0    1   tom   a1
3    4  tick   d1
4    1   tom   a2
7    4  tick   d2
8    1   tom   a3
11   4  tick   d3
12   1   tom   a4
13   4  tick   d4
14   1   tom   a5
16   4  tick   d5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [value_counts()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), then, if you want to, you can reset the index [reset_index()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

```
s = df.name.value_counts()
print(df[df.name.isin(s[s > 4].index)].reset_index(drop=True))
    name  id text
0   tom   1  a1 
1  tick   4  d1
2   tom   1  a2 
3  tick   4  d2
4   tom   1  a3 
5  tick   4  d3
6   tom   1  a4 
7  tick   4  d4
8   tom   1  a5 
9  tick   4  d5
```

Comment: thanks for your answers. it is better to add how to get the s, I mean s = df.name.values_counts().

Comment: @tktktk0711 Wow, I had that line there, then when I edited it I guess I forgot to insert it again. Thanks for catching that. Please see my edit.